# JetBrains WebStorm: "Unresolved variable prototype"

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, webstorm

While running a code inspection, I get many errors in my Node.js code indicating that I am referencing an undefined property `prototype` on my various classes. I don't understand as `prototype` should be on all objects.

For example:

```
var DeliveryFormatter = require('./_DeliveryFormatter.Abstract');
/**
 * @extends DeliveryFormatter
 */
function JSONDeliveryFormatter () {
    // ...
}

JSONDeliveryFormatter.prototype = Object.create(DeliveryFormatter.prototype);
```

All the code is running correctly, so I know that `DeliveryFormatter` is resolving, but I get a wavy underline under the `prototype` word in `Object.create(DeliveryFormatter.prototype)`. How can I get WebStorm to resolve the `prototype` object?

Comment: Please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, Restart) - does the problem persist? If yes, I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: Only functions do have a `.prototype` property. Does Webstorm resolve the `DeliveryFormatter` properly?

Comment: @lena - I still have this exact same issue with WebStorm 10.0.4 (Build #WS-141.1550) on a Mac. Is this a known bug when the underlying function is being resolved via `require` from an external module?

Comment: Same problem with the 2016.1 version of WebStorm.